# ws2812b on ATTiny85

Tags: c, avr, led, attiny

I have ATTiny with 1MHz clock. I'm trying to light up some ws2812b led strip. I conected everything without any resistors and capacitors. I think everything should works but it doesn't :)
I'm useing light_ws2812 library https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812.
Below is example code. I have hanged only F_CPU frequency, numper of output pin and reset time in config file. Could You help me find the problem and advice how can I fix it?

**MAIN**

```
#define F_CPU 1000000

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "ws2812_config.h"
#include "light_ws2812.h"

struct cRGB led[2];

int main(void)
{

    uint8_t pos=0;
    uint8_t direction=1;
    uint8_t i;

    #ifdef __AVR_ATtiny10__
    CCP=0xD8;       // configuration change protection, write signature
    CLKPSR=0;       // set cpu clock prescaler =1 (8Mhz) (attiny 4/5/9/10)
    #endif

    led[0].r=255;led[0].g=00;led[0].b=00;       // LED 0 is red
    led[1].r=255;led[1].g=16;led[1].b=16;       // LED 1 is White

    while(1)
    {

        for (i=0; i<pos; i++)
        ws2812_sendarray((uint8_t *)&led[0],3);         // Repeatedly send "red" to the led string.
        // No more than 1-2µs should pass between calls
        // to avoid issuing a reset condition.
        for (i=0; i<(16-pos); i++)
        ws2812_sendarray((uint8_t *)&led[1],3);         // white

        _delay_ms(50);                                      // Issue reset and wait for 50 ms.

        pos+=direction;
        if ((pos==16)||(pos==0)) direction=-direction;
    }

}
```

**CONFIG**

```
/*
 * light_ws2812_config.h
 *
 * v2.4 - Nov 27, 2016
 *
 * User Configuration file for the light_ws2812_lib
 *
 */ 


#ifndef WS2812_CONFIG_H_
#define WS2812_CONFIG_H_

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Define Reset time in µs. 
//
// This is the time the library spends waiting after writing the data.
//
// WS2813 needs 300 µs reset time
// WS2812 and clones only need 50 µs
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define ws2812_resettime  50

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Define I/O pin
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#define ws2812_port B     // Data port 
#define ws2812_pin  3     // Data out pin

#endif /* WS2812_CONFIG_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 1Mhz is just too slow to be able to generate the signals required by the WS2812B.

The most timing critical WS2812B signal - the TH0 pulse - must be less than 500ns wide, and at 1Mhz, each MCU cycle is 1000ns.

More info on the the WS2812B timing constraints here...

https://wp.josh.com/2014/05/13/ws2812-neopixels-are-not-so-finicky-once-you-get-to-know-them/

Comment: Wow. Thank You for this article. I will increase my clock to 8MHz. I hope i will be works

Comment: Unfortunatly after changing fuses and F_CPU to 8MHz still doesn't work :(

Comment: Ok. I have found a problem. I will post the solution later

Comment: @Adam You should pass your F_CPU by command line parameters to all compiled source files. It's kinda pointless to change it inside of main and nothing else doesn't know it. Also you have to change fuses to switch to internal 8MHz clock without ckdiv8 because F_CPU doesn't actually change the real cpu frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Series resistors and parallel capacitors do help decrease noise that causes inexplicable behavior. But you're right, it should not stop the WS2812bs from working completely.

I suggest you try another pin on your attiny. Pin 3 is used for usb communication. If you are powering your attiny through a usb cable connected to your computer this will cause trouble. Try pins 5 and 6 for example.

You can try the Adafruit_NeoPixel library. I tried and it compiled for attiny85 without modification. I did not actually try to run it since I do not have an attiny lying around.

Also, some of the cheaper WS2812b ledstrips that are around on ebay got their Din and Dout labels switched. This means you have to connect the Dout pin to your attiny. This has actually happened to me once.

I don't know about pulse lenghts in WS2812bs but if that is not the issue I'm pretty sure it's one of the three I mentioned above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You for response. I'm powering it just by wires conected to 5V . I've tried use differnet pin but it didn't work. I can't use Adafruit_NeoPixel  because I'm not useing Arduino IDE :) I've also tried conected dout to my MCU but still nothing. But I will try add some capasitors. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Solution]

According to README I've included config file before header in my MAIN source code file. It was a mistake because the two files are part of different compilation units and DEFINEs are not shared between them. It causes that my configuration settings was ignored and program used default (not correct in my case) ones.

To fix this bug You should include Your ws2812_config.h within light_ws2812.h

Answer (score 0):

You should use the library `FASTLED`,you can download it on arduino ide .It's very easy to light WS2812 with ATTINY85 by using this library.